# How do I decode columns in the exp_sites table?

Tags: database, how-to, site-preferences

I need to look at the contents of the site_system_preferences column in the exp_sites table. How do I decode this data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The encoded string stored in the site_system_preferences column is a base64 encoded serialized array. Follow these steps to both unserialize and decode the string:

1. Go to http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/index.php
2. Paste the entire string from the site_system_preferences column into the "Unserializer input" textarea field on the left of the page
3. Make sure to select the "base64 decode (top level)" checkbox located at the bottom right
   of the field
4. Click the "Unserialize" button

This will show you the contents of the site_system_preferences column.

---

This also applies to these columns in the exp_sites table:

- site_mailinglist_preferences
- site_member_preferences
- site_template_preferences
- site_channel_preferences
- site_bootstrap_checksums
- site_pages

Comment: Sweet! I'll send you my invoice:)